# Netsuite - using Suitescript attach a image from file cabinet to custom record attachments

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I currently have a custom record which have the image field where the end user can  upload one image. Now my end user want to attach multiple images, so we have turned on attachments (files tab) and want to run a scheduled script to move the current image from the image field to file tab?

According to my research there is no files suitescript Api, so is it possible to do this with suitescript?

Answer (score 2):

nlapiAttachRecord("file", imagefieldvalue, "customerecordid", recordid);